# How to increment all elements in an array or slice in golang

Tags: arrays, loops, go

Below code increments only ith element of that slice. Is there something inbuild that i can increment all elements with 1. Please suggest.

```
for i:= 0; i< k ;i++{
    if(slice[i] < K){
        slice[i] = slice[i] + 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working with slices you will find that you will gravitate towards `for` loops. Go doesn't have extra functions for slices that you might find with other languages.

```
for i := range slice {
  slice[i]++
}
```